# Maximum test messages in a day with high volume in RC

Tags: ringcentral

In RingCentral if I need to send high volume of messages, the is the maximum number of messages we can send in a day? Is there any limit in SMS text size?

Also read somewhere that Ringcentral has created some new kind of Api which will produce high volume of messages per day.. but we need to apply for that.. any link for that? Where is the new API of RingCentral for high volume of sms text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1,000 messages per day with a limit of 200 unique numbers which is what written in https://ringcentral-faq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sms/
Message size should be up to 160 characters and can concatenate longer messages up to 1000 characters.

Yes,there is new API for High Volume A2P SMS which can handle massive up to 250,000 message a day. You need to send a request via this form.

ref: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/10338/sms-limit.html